# How to initialise a fixed-size ListArray in pyarrow from a numpy array efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, pyarrow, apache-arrow

How would I efficiently initialise a fixed-size [`pyarray.ListArray`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ListArray.html#pyarrow.ListArray)
from a suitably prepared numpy array?

The [documentation of `pyarray.array`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html#list-arrays) indicates that a nested iterable input structure works, but in practice that does not work if the outer iterable is a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa

n = 1000
w = 3

data = np.arange(n*w,dtype="i2").reshape(-1,w)

# this works:
pa.array(list(data),pa.list_(pa.int16(),w))
# this fails:
pa.array(data,pa.list_(pa.int16(),w))
# -> ArrowInvalid: only handle 1-dimensional arrays
```

It seems ridiculus to split an input array directly matching the Arrow specification into `n` separate arrays and then re-assemble from there.

[`pyarray.ListArray.from_arrays`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ListArray.html#pyarrow.ListArray.from_arrays) seems to require an `offsets` argument, which only has a meaning for variable-size lists.

Comment: I don't know anything about `pyarrow`, but if it is happy with lists and nested lists, `arr.tolist()` is an efficjent way of producing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for pyarrow.FixedSizeListArray.from_arrays which, regrettably, appears undocumented (I went ahead and filed [a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13101))

You'll want to reshape your numpy array as a contiguous array first.

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa

len = 10
width = 3
# Or just skip the initial reshape but keeping it in to simulate real data
arr = np.arange(len*width,dtype="i2").reshape(-1,width)
arr.shape = -1
pa.FixedSizeListArray.from_arrays(arr, width)
```

Comment: So this doesn't work anymore? `arr.shape=-1` usage throws an error.

Comment: What error?  I just confirmed this still works with pyarrow 12 and numpy 1.24.3

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It works. I didn't reshape the arr and was was trying to call arr.shape = -1